# Andengine Text not support Arabic

Tags: android, andengine, arabic

I'm working now in a game in Android which supports many languages. I use Andengine but when I draw Text using **Andengine** as this:

```
Text text = new Text(float pX, float pY, IFont pFont, CharSequence pText, VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager);
```

It doesn't show the letters of **Arabic** language correctly.Could any one help me?

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Comment: Android 2.2 but it is not the problem, when i display **Arabic** words inside Alerts it appears correctly